# Looking for a web API which can test if a port is open

Tags: curl, port-scanning

There are of course many ways to check if a port is open on a server (nmap, netcat, yougetsignal.com), however, I am curious if anyone knows of a website that has an API that would be callable from a tool such as curl. Ideally something along the lines of `curl -s https://isitopen.somesite.com/myserver.com/80` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this API provided by Hackertarget.com.  It is still in beta though.

`https://api.hackertarget.com/nmap/?q=myserver.com`

[Reference](https://hackertarget.com/tcp-port-scan/)